# A circle centered at $(0,2)$ is tangent to $y=x^2$ at exactly two points. What is its radius?

Tags: derivatives, circles, conic-sections, tangent-line

> A circle is centered at $(0,2)$ and is tangent to $y=x^2$ at exactly two points. What is the radius of the circle?

Don't really have an idea at how to solve the problem. Help is appreciated!

Comment: The tangent to a circle is perpendicular to its radius at the point of tangency.

Comment: So what? Is there a way to use that to an advantage?

Comment: A reply "So what?" does not fit someone ready to learn... The amd's hint is not 'to use to an advantage' — it's a way of solving the problem! Find the tangents to parabola, which are perpendicular to the respecitve directions from the circle's center to tangency points. If respective points of tangency are in equal distances from the clrcle's center, you got the solution.

Comment: I don't underatand how "so what" equates to "someone [not] ready to learn." Doesn't "so what" represent inquiry? Dosn't "so what" give power to the hands of the receiver? I'm literally going into submission and agreeing that the receiver has more knowledge, hence the nees to ask a question that shows no understanding on my part. Also, how does "to use as an advantage" not equate to "a way of solving the problem?" Isn't finding a way to solve a problem and "advantage?" You had way too many fallacies in your comment that it's almost unbearable.

Comment: Find points on the parabola for which the normals—perpendiculars to the tangents—pass through the given center point. Pick out the pair that are at the same distance from that center. That distance is the radius you’re supposed to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,x^2)$ be a point on the parabola.

Line through $(0,2)$ and $(x,x^2)$ has slope:

$m:=\dfrac{2-x^2}{-x}.$

Slope of parabola at $x$: $m':= dy/dx =2x.$

$mm' =-1$, perpendicular.

$\dfrac{2-x^2}{-x} = -\dfrac{1}{2x}.$

$x=^+_-\sqrt{3/2},$ and  $y= 3/2$. $        $
(On the parabola);

Insert $(x,y)$ into

$x^2 +(y-2)^2=r^2 $

to find:

$ r= \sqrt{ 7/4 }.$

Answer (score 2):

The circle has equation
$$x^2+(y-2)^2=r^2.$$
It meets the parabola at the points with $x$-coordinates satisfying
$$x^2+(x^2-2)^2=r^2.\tag1$$
Although this is a quartic equation, it is quadratic in $x^2$.
Thus
$$(z-2)^2+z-r^2=0\tag2$$
for $z=x^2$
For the circle to be tangent at two points, (1) must have two pairs of repeated roots, and so (2) has a repeated root. There is a well-known
criterion for a quadratic to have a repeated root ....

Comment: Using the substitution $x^2 \to y$ instead of $y \to x^2$ gets you to a quadratic (this time, in $y$) more-directly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a,b)$ is the meet point which lies on $y=x^2$ so $b=a^2$. The tangent line on $y=x^2$ is of the form 
$$y-b=2a(x-a)$$
which is perpendicular to radius of circle, so the line passes through $(0,2)$ and $(a,b)$ is 
$$y=-\dfrac{x}{2a}+2$$
the intersection of these lines shows $a=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac32}$ then $R$ is the distance $(0,2)$ from tangent line $y=2ax-a^2$, that is 
$$R=\dfrac{2+a^2}{\sqrt{4a^2+1}}=\dfrac12\sqrt{7}$$

Comment: How did you obtain $y=2ax−a^2$ ?

Comment: $y-b=2a(x-a)$ and $b=a^2$.